# Drupal 6 as a call logging system - question about node performance & scalability

Tags: 6, nodes, entities, performance

We currently use Drupal as a Knowledge, communications and assessments system for our call centre agents and it is working great. However there has been a request that this to also handle our call logging.

We utilise profiles to allow manager roles to check their team members assessment scores and what communications they have read, the idea is that they could also do the same with calls taken.

My concern here is that this will **dramatically increase the number of nodes** from what we have now (articles, comms etc are all created by our team so nodes will be within the 1000's).

If we employ Drupal for logging calls this would mean that our 1000's of agents would be creating dozens of call logs per day. This potentially would push nodes up into the 1000000's.

Would Drupal and its node / cck be able to cope with this type of load where 1000's of users would be submitting dozens of nodes simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a subjective question. Your best bet would be to ask on some of the Drupal groups that handle this stuff like [Drupal High Performance](http://groups.drupal.org/high-performance).

There are so many factors in making a drupal site scale it's hard to list them all.

[Pressflow](http://fourkitchens.com/pressflow-makes-drupal-scale) is a drupal distro that is built for scaling, they also have some great blog articles on scaling.

Comment: Unfortunately we have been using Drupal 6 for the past year so I dont think it would be possible to switch to Pressflow or am I missing something?

Comment: Pressflow is a fork of Drupal 6 which includes a few patches that didn't make it into core. Switching to pressflow is as simple and downloading it copying your sites folder to it and then changing the vhost.

Comment: Wow I didnt realise it was that easy, thanks for the tip I will look into Press Flow now.